java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
I am getting this error while building gradlew with Android Studio.
Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 1.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:349)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.writeBuffer(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:98)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:85)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

> Task :app:testDebugUnitTest FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\nodejs;.;C:\MyProjects\rtr05-083\MyAndroid\01-IDE\app\src\testDebug\jniLibs;C:\MyProjects\rtr05-083\MyAndroid\01-IDE\app\src\test\jniLibs
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\nodejs;/;C:\MyProjects\rtr05-083\MyAndroid\01-IDE\app\src\testDebug\jniLibs;C:\MyProjects\rtr05-083\MyAndroid\01-IDE\app\src\test\jniLibs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
> Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 38s
78 actionable tasks: 78 executed

I would really appreciate some help!
I was expecting it to build successfully.

You'll have more luck if you share your Gradle set up.

I installed android studio, and gradle was automatically set up into it. I just added the environmental path variables.
